# UITabBarController push new view controller in fullscreen

Tags: ios, navigation

I have a UITabBarController and a few tabs, each associated with a child view controller.

Now in one of those child view controller, if I push a view controller, it doesn't push in fullscreen, but rather "above" the UITabBar.

How can I push it in fullscreen?

P.S I already tried the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` option, when the destination view controller is present, I can see a blank area at the bottom, then the view is stretched to fill that blank area, look weird.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply `hideTabBarsWhenPushed` on pushed view controller.

Comment: This is the way! I spent two hours talking to AI and it keeps giving wrong advices. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before you push to the target viewController you should set targetViewController's `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to Yes
**Like this:**

```
    ......

    targetViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];

    ......
```